# How is it possible that my jQuery code breaks a function *in* Google hosted jquery.min.js?

Tags: jquery

I am getting an error:

> Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child

from my Google hosted jquery.min.js file.

It works when my function is like this:

```
 var screenPos = "init";
 var screenPos2 = "init";
 var col3 = false;

function projectPos(){

    $(".article").each(function(){
   $(this).find(".theProject").css('left','0px');
   $(this).find(".theExtra").css('left','608px');
    });


    $(".article:nth-child("+screenPos+"+4)").find(".theProject").css('left','-304px');
    $(".article:nth-child("+screenPos+"+4)").find(".theExtra").css('left','-304px');

}
```

But if I add this into the function:

```
   if (col3 = true){
   $(".article:nth-child("+screenPos2+"+4)").find(".theProject").css('left','-304px');
   $(".article:nth-child("+screenPos2+"+4)").find(".theExtra").css('left','-304px');
   }
```

I suddenly get this error from within the google hosted jquery file.

How is that possible?
I already have a few nth-child checks in there, so why would a third one break it?

Very curious.

The page in question is here: [marckremers.com/2011](http://marckremers.com/2011)

PS - the site is in development, I'll leave the error in there, commented out, for reference

Comment: `if (col3 = true)` shouldn't it be  `if (col3 == true)` ?

Comment: Have you double-checked the value of `screenPos2` at the point you're making the call?

Comment: posting the link to your site is not helpful unless you identify which file has the code in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if (col3 **=** true) should'nt be if (col3 **==** true)?

Comment: omg for real? My Bad.. but why does it break another js file then? Don't understand the logic of that.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be sending `init4` as the parameter to `nth-child()`.  As far [as I can see](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/), that's not a legal value.

If the value of `screenPos2` is being modified elsewhere *before* this is called, then you need to log that.

Comment: +1 it should be `int` to grab the nth child and index start with 0 for the first element :)

Comment: Sorry ignore the init... it's getting a "'somthing'n" from another function.

Comment: so what value _does_ `screenPos2` have when this is called?